# Add Association by using Non-Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, associations

I want to manually add the Association between **Qualification** and **QualificationUnit** by using the Non-keys.  Qualification has a Zero-To-Many relationship to QualificationUnit

I want to join OakQualificationNumber and QualificationNumber.

The below is the database structure and entity diagram in my project.

[image]

I tried to associate them but I couldn't.  I couldn't change the PrincipalKey to OakQualificationNumber.  Could you please advise me how I could add the Association with Non Key Fields?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If `QualificationNumber` isn't a key, how do you expect this to work?

Comment: QualificationID is autoincrement value.  So, we used it as a key.  But the OakQualificationNumber is the real key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. EF does not support unique constraints yet and because of that principal key can be only primary key.